# Chrome DevTools Protocol - intercepting and modifying websocket requests

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to use the `Chrome DevTools Protocol` (`CDP`) to intercept web requests and modify them.

The problem is that I need to modify the headers of a WebSocket request. Is this possible?

I can modify the headers of "normal" requests easily by first sending messages:

```
Network.enable
Network.setRequestInterception
```

and then listening for the `Network.requestIntercepted` message and replying with an appropriate `Network.continueInterceptedRequest` message.

However, `Network.requestIntercepted` does not get called for WebSockets. I can listen for `Network.webSocketWillSendHandshakeRequest` but this only lets me read the request, I don't see any way to modify it.

Is there a way to do this, or is this impossible at the moment?

Comment: The documentation says setRequestInterception is deprecated and suggests using [Fetch](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch). The latter has WebSocket in its RequestPattern type so maybe it can actually intercept it.

Comment: @wOxxOm: thanks for your comment, but it doesn't seem to work.... I tried using it (tried both with and without an explicit pattern), but like the old version it only seems to intercept "normal" requests, not websocket ones...

Comment: Bug report about not being able to use Fetch with WebSocket resource type: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1283412

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further testing of all possible combinations, I came to the conclusion that this cannot be done, unfortunately.

If I'm wrong, feel free to correct me and I'll accept your answer and delete this one.